# Is there a Git command that pulls latest from branch_x and merges into my current branch?

Tags: git

A typical way of working with Git for me is to branch off `feat1` from `dev`. Then I commit code into `feat1`. Before submitting a merge request via the GitLab UI, I want to ensure that `feat1` is up to date with `dev` (maybe another developer on my team merged something into `dev` in the mean time).

What I do via the local git client is:

```
git checkout dev
git pull
git checkout -
git merge dev
```

I presume I am doing this wrong and that there's an easier way to do this. Is there a command that looks like (when I have currently checked out branch `feat1`) `git do_some_stuff dev` that has the effect I want?

Comment: Haven't done merging via the console, but i believe `git merge origin/dev` would be what you are looking for, with the `origin/` referring to the current point of the branch on the server rather than your local branch

Comment: `git pull origin dev` from your branch is fine. It'll `fetch` all remote refs, then merge `origin/dev` into your currently checked out local branch. The main difference with your current process is that it won't keep your local `dev` branch up-to-date. But if you never commit on it, it might be irrelevant.

Comment: I think you just want `git rebase dev` ?

Comment: @Randommm You have to do a `git fetch` before `git merge origin/dev` because `origin/dev` resides in your repository, not *on the server*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most definitely want [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

- `git pull origin dev` will `fetch` refs and then `merge` `origin/dev` into your current branch (assuming `feat1`)
- `git pull --rebase origin dev` will `fetch` refs and then `rebase` local `feat1` on top of `origin/dev`. Note that rebasing will rewrite your history and drop/recreate your local commits

The following ASCII diagrams should make the difference between the two approaches clearer.

Initial local history:

```
-D1-D2                  < dev
      `F1-F2            < feat1
```

Remote history:

```
      ,D3-D4            < origin/dev
-D1-D2
```

Using `pull` (with merge strategy):

```
      ,D3-D4            < origin/dev
-D1-D2      \           < dev
      `F1-F2-F3         < feat1
```

After `pull --rebase`:

```
      ,D3-D4            < origin/dev
-D1-D2      \           < dev
             F1'-F2'    < feat1
```

Alternatively, you can manually and explicitly run `fetch` followed by `merge` or `rebase`. The resulting history will be identical, but the local branches will also be updated to match their remote-tracking counterparts:

- `git fetch origin dev:dev && git merge dev`
- `git fetch origin dev:dev && git rebase dev`

No need to switch/checkout branches back and forth.

Comment: Thanks @knittl, this is a lovely answer!

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is evil because it has so many indeterminate aspects (things depend on your `git config` setup), and it does nothing you can't do some other way. Moreover, if you are never going to merge manually into `dev`, you don't need a local `dev` and you shouldn't have one, as it is just confusing you.

Instead, simply stay in the branch you are in, and say

```
git fetch; git merge origin/dev
```